# Streaming MJPEG inside ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic3, video-streaming, html5-video

**Environment:** I have a phone that connects to a **black box camera** that expose a stream in MJPEG at http://192.168.10.123:7060 and a smartphone which main aim is to get the stream and visualize it. Imagine they are already connected via the camera built-in Wifi.

**Limits:** I need to do it via Ionic 3.

**Bonus point**: I need to build a controller upon the raw stream of data to stop, reload, and possibly capture something from it.

**What I already done (*failing*):**

```
<ion-content>
    The world is your oyster. Let's see the stream.

    <video src="http://192.168.10.123:7060/" controls>
    <!-- <video src="http://192.168.10.123:7060/manifest(format=mpeg)" controls> -->
        Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> element.
    </video>
<ion-content>
```

I also tryed (as I saw that on various articles) to add *manifest(format=mjpg)* after the already wrote URL.
The result is a blank video element that reproduces nothing.
I also tried the functionality of this HTML5 component using a sample online video and everything worked well.

My second attempt at trying to retrieve something from this IP+PORT was using https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media
but nothing changed, I get the same result that I had with the HTML 5 component.

Third attempt: I tried using VLC to see if the stream was visible and yes, it is. Also, I acquired the information I reported in the **environment** section.

**The main question**: 
What other paths should I take to solve my retrieve my result and complete my task with my limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg to stream mjpeg

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('video-canvas');
this.player = new JSMpeg.Player(this.button.url ,{canvas: canvas});
```